# Problem with using smart card usb certificate in WebView in UWP application

Tags: webview, uwp, certificate, usb, smartcard

I write UWP application with WebView. I load to WebView web site that uses hardware usb smart card with pin code to authenticate users. I enable capability Share User Certificates to allow UWP app to access hardware certificates on usb. When i try to log in with certificate in the web site its popup dialog to select certificate but its different with those who popup in the normal browser like Edge and when i click "OK" dialog for enter pin code, dialog for the pin code does not popup and authentication on web site fails.
Popup dialog in UWP application with webview:

[image]

the same web site in IE shows these popup dialog:

[image]

As you see the info in two dialogs about certificates its different. The UWP webview seems like not have full access to the smart card and can not get all info from the card. Does anyone have similar problem and does have a solution? I search in the internet and stackoverflow but does not find a solution about this problem.

Comment: When you clicked "OK" button from dialog for entering pin code, what error message did you receive?

Comment: I didn't get error message just the same dialog appears and when click "OK" web site says that authentication fails because pin code is not entered. Dialog for pin code does not appears